Flux concat is not working after spring upgrade to 3.2.3
return Flux.concat(SmsTemplate.transferTo(SmsTemplateFile),lSMSVariables.transferTo(SMSVariablesFile))
                   .then(importService.previewSmsTemplateImport(clientId,
                                                                spaceKey,
                                                                new FileSystemResource(SmsTemplateFile),
                                                                new FileSystemResource(SMSVariablesFile)))
                   .map(mapper::map)
                   .doFinally($ -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(SmsTemplateFile.toFile()))
                   .doFinally($ -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(SMSVariablesFile.toFile()));


SmsTemplate.transferTo(SmsTemplateFile),SMSVariables.transferTo(SMSVariablesFile)

this code is not working after the spring boot3 upgrade but if I am using the below code it's working fine. it's not writing the data from one file to another file and because of that, I am getting errors because the file which I am reading is empty.
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : parsing initialization error: org.gjt.xpp.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed outside root element at line 1 and column 1 

SmsTemplate.transferTo(SmsTemplateFile).subscribe();
SMSVariables.transferTo(SMSVariablesFile).subscribe();

but I can't use subscribe. this code is working in spring-web:5.2.10.RELEASE but not working with spring-web:6.1.5.

"this code is not working" - HOW is it not working. Please explain and include all relevant error messages and stack trace.  "I can't use subscribe" - WHY?

@JimGarrison because subscribe will will get Threading issue.

I got the solution as below Thanks @JimGarrison. I have use Mono.defer(() ->.

return Flux.concat(
lookupSmsTemplate.transferTo(lookupSmsTemplateFile),
lookupSMSVariables.transferTo(lookupSMSVariablesFile))
.then(Mono.defer(() -> importService.previewSmsTemplateImport(
clientId,
spaceKey,
new FileSystemResource(lookupSmsTemplateFile),
new FileSystemResource(lookupSMSVariablesFile))))
.map(mapper::map)
.doFinally($ -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(lookupSmsTemplateFile.toFile()))
.doFinally($ -> FileUtils.deleteQuietly(lookupSMSVariablesFile.toFile()));

You can answer your own question, and after a few days you can mark the answer as accepted.  Please do that instead of providing the answer in a comment.
